# Curve connecting two points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ passing through a hyperplane

Tags: geometry, permutations, coordinate-systems, plane-curves

Let $\pi$ and $\lambda$ be two distinct permutations of $1, 2, . . . , n$, and consider the points $p := (\pi(1),\pi(2), ... , \pi(n))$ and $r:= (\lambda(1), \lambda(2), ... , \lambda(n))$ **in $\mathbb{R}^n$**.

Because $\pi$ and $\lambda$ are distinct, there are indices $i$ and $j$ with $1\leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$, such that $\pi(i) < \pi(j )$ and $\lambda(i) > \lambda(j )$. (if not both permutations are the same)

It has been claimed that:

> The points $p$ and $r$ are on different sides of
>   the hyperplane $x_i$ = $x_j$ . Any continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ between $p$ and $r$ must pass through this hyperplane

I would like to know why is this claim true?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the continuous curve $C:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^n$ start at $p$ and end at $q$. So $C(0)=p$ and $C(1)=q$ Consider the continuous function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x_1\cdots x_n)=x_i-x_j$. Composition of these functions is still continuous, $f\circ C: [0,1]\to\mathbb R$. What beautiful theorem of calculus should we now apply? :-).

P.S: let me know if you want me to finish the argument. I think it would be helpful for you finish it.

$f \circ C(0)=f(p)=\pi (i)-\pi(j)<0 $ and $f \circ C(1)=f(q)=\lambda(i)-\lambda(j)>0$. 
So what does the intermediate value theorem say about this function somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Beautiful hint. +1

Comment: I really have no idea :)

Comment: What theorem I should use to complete the proof?

Comment: Evaluate the new function at $0$ and evaluate it at $1$ and then apply the intermediate value theorem

Comment: Because 0 is between f(0) and f(1), so there is number *x* in [0,1] such that *f(x)=0* and *f(x_1,...,x_n) = x_i - x_j* so there is a point where *x_i = x_j*. Right?

Comment: @Drupalist Exactly!